# Image Processing - Rotation and Optical Character Recognizion

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, captcha

Good Morning everybody,

Today I wanna concern about the topic "Image Manipulation in C++".

So far I am able to filter all the noisy stuff out of the picture and change the color to black and white.

But now I have two questions.

**First Question**:
Below you see a screenshot of the image. What is the best way to find out how to rotate the text. In the end it would be nice if the text is horizontal. Does anybody have a good link or an example.

[image]

**Second Question:**
How to go on? Do you think I should send the image to an "Optical Character Recognizer" **(a)** or should I filter out each letter **(b)**?
If the answer is **(a)** what is the smallest ocr lib? All libs I found so far seem to be overpowered and difficult to implement in an existing project. (like gocr or tesseract)

If the answer is **(b)** what is the best way to save each letter as an own image? Shoul i search for an white pixel an than go from pixel to pixel an save the coordinates in an 2D Array? What is with the letter "i" ;)

Thanks to everybody who will help me to find my way!
Sorry for the strange english above. I'm still a language ***noob*** :-)

Comment: Dividing an image into parts containing only one character is a non-trivial task and belongs to the OCR, too. So you should send the whole image. As example of non-trivial case, see http://www.markboulton.co.uk/images/uploads/2.gif

Comment: Are you seriously asking for help to programatically break a captcha?  As in the challenge that was designed SPECIFICALLY to make it difficult if not impossible to use OCR systems to read them?

Comment: No I am not asking how to break a captcha. My main question is how I can find out how to rotate the text in an image so that the text is horizontal.

Comment: @Spence Usually true, but that is not the case in the example, for sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The usual name for the problem in your first question is "Skew Correction"**

[image]

You may Google for it (lot of references). A nice paper [**here**](http://www.papamarkos.gr/uploaded-files/Papaparkos/Journals/Volume%20No.22,%20Issue%20No.4%20of%20International%20Journal%20of%20Pattern%20Recognition%20and%20Artificial%20Intelligence%20%28IJPRAI%29%20P691.pdf), showing for example how to get this:

[image]

An easy way to start (but not as good as the previously mentioned), is to perform a [**Principal Component Analysis**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For your first question:

First, Remove any "specs" of noisy white pixels that aren't part of the letter sequence.  A gentle low-pass filter (pixel color = average of surrounding pixels) followed by a clamping of the pixel values to pure black or pure white.  This should get rid of the little "dot" underneath the "a" character in your image and any other specs.

Now search for the following pixels:

```
xMin = white pixel with the lowest  x value (white pixel closest to the left edge)
xMax = white pixel with the largest x value (white pixel closest to the right edge)
yMin = white pixel with the lowest  y value (white pixel closest to the top edge)
yMax = white pixel with the largest y value (white pixel closest to the bottom edge)

with these four pixel values, form a bounding box: Rect(xMin, yMin, xMax, yMax);
compute the area of the bounding box and find the center.

using the center of the bounding box, rotate the box by N degrees. (You can pick N: 1 degree would be an ok value).

Repeat the process of finding xMin,xMax,yMin,yMax and recompute the area

Continue rotating by N degrees until you've rotated K degrees.  Also rotate by -N degrees until you've rotated by -K degrees.  (Where K is the max rotation... say 30 degrees). At each step recompute the area of the bounding box.
```

The rotation that produces the bounding box with the smallest area is likely the rotation that aligns the letters parallel to the bottom edge (horizontal alignment).

Answer (score 0):

You could measure the height to each white pixel from the bottom and find how much the text is leaning. It's a very simple approach but it worked fine for me when I tried it.